# How to do merge datatable fields?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

database table fields : id,first_name,last_name,email

datatable : full_name,email   (without id) ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            var table = $('#havuz_table').DataTable({

                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],

                "ajax": "{{URL::to('ajaxUzmanListesi/')}}",
                "language": {
                    "url": '/lib/datatables/language/Turkish.json'
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "mData": null ,
                        "mRender" : function ( data, type, full ) {
                            return full['first_name']+''+full['last_name'];}
                    }

                ]

});
```

});

Comment: Generally, you do it on server-side. Are you sure you wanna do it on the client-side?

Comment: Please make a fiddle to solve your problem.

Comment: Having PHP do it on server-side.

Comment: php server side return datatable json data. I made sql concat but  didnt work datatable search full name

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
"columns": [{
        "data": null,
        "title": "Name",
        "render": function(data, type, full) {
            return full['first_name'] + ' ' + full['last_name'];
        }
    },
    {
        "data": "email",
        "title": "Email"
    }
]
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/9ep3yzg0/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. this code working. First, I want to add a certain amount of data and later make a request for ajax to switch to search and next pages. How can we do ?

Comment: I think you perhaps need to ask further questions and try to figure it out yourself first. There's so much documentation about DataTables here and on the main site: https://datatables.net/